# Flume HDFS Sink generates lots of tiny files on HDFS

Tags: hdfs, flume, flume-ng

I have a toy setup sending log4j messages to hdfs using flume.  I'm not able to configure the hdfs sink to avoid many small files.  I thought I could configure the hdfs sink to create a new file every-time the file size reaches 10mb, but it is still creating files around 1.5KB.

Here is my current flume config:

```
a1.sources=o1
a1.sinks=i1
a1.channels=c1

#source configuration
a1.sources.o1.type=avro
a1.sources.o1.bind=0.0.0.0
a1.sources.o1.port=41414

#sink config
a1.sinks.i1.type=hdfs
a1.sinks.i1.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/myName/flume/events
#never roll-based on time
a1.sinks.i1.hdfs.rollInterval=0
#10MB=10485760
a1.sinks.il.hdfs.rollSize=10485760
#never roll base on number of events
a1.sinks.il.hdfs.rollCount=0

#channle config
a1.channels.c1.type=memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity=1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity=100

a1.sources.o1.channels=c1
a1.sinks.i1.channel=c1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is your typo in conf.

```
#sink config
a1.sinks.i1.type=hdfs
a1.sinks.i1.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/myName/flume/events
#never roll-based on time
a1.sinks.i1.hdfs.rollInterval=0
#10MB=10485760
a1.sinks.il.hdfs.rollSize=10485760
#never roll base on number of events
a1.sinks.il.hdfs.rollCount=0
```

where in the line 'rollSize' and 'rollCount', you put **il** as **i1**.
Please try to use DEBUG, then you will find like:

```
[SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.shouldRotate:465)  - rolling: rollSize: 1024, bytes: 1024
```

Due to **il**, default value of rollSize 1024 is being used .

Comment: According to your example, as far I understand, write will occur every 10Mb.
But what will trigger write for last 5Mb in case of 15Mb file.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS Sink has a property `hdfs.batchSize` (default 100) which describes "number of events written to file before it is flushed to HDFS". I think that's your problem here.

Consider also checking all other properties: [HDFS Sink](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink) .

Comment: no that didn't work either.  Could it be because of the channel?

Comment: The batching in the sink is time-based as well as size-based. You could consider something like Edward Capriolo's File Crusher https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/filecrush

Comment: @Sarge - But I've turned off the time-based version of it: a1.sinks.i1.hdfs.rollInterval=0.  Surely, this must have been solved, creating lots of tiny files in hdfs is not good for the node-name.

Answer (score 0):

This can possibly happen because of the memory channel and its capacity. I guess its dumping data to HDFS as soon as its capacity becomes full. Did you try using file channel instead of memory ?

Comment: yes I did use the file channel same thing...I feel like I'm missing something fundamental...