# Gobblin Kafka to HDFS: append to the same file

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, gobblin

Is it any way to append new messages from Kafka to the same file in the HDFS using Gobblin? Now it creates a new file every time reading from Kafka. If run Gobblin job every minute for example,it will be the plenty of files.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of Gobblin, but IMHO [Apache Flume](https://flume.apache.org/) will be a better choice for you.

Comment: As I know, Flume cannot append to the same file as well.

Comment: 1. Writing files into same folder, MR/Spark can read all files within a folder given path to folder.

Comment: Flume won't create a billion files if you configure properly it can roll events into same file. check this out. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169921/flume-hdfs-sink-generates-lots-of-tiny-files-on-hdfs